# Ввод своих команд в bash

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, bash, сервер

Как вводить свои команды в terminal ubuntu? Например, вот я захожу postgresql `sudo -u postrgres psql`, и дальше мне нужно начать вводить команды: `CREATE TABLE images (id VARCHAR, image VARCHAR);` Не понимаю как это делать через скрипт, только знакомлюсь с bash'ом, рыскал информацию по типу `echo`, ввод отдельно нажатием каких то кнопок через библиотеки, `expect` не понимаю почему не работает. Пожалуйста, объясните, как вводить собственные команды в `terminal` используя `bash`. Просто мне нужно сделать `bash` скрипт по установке всего, и в том числе настроить `postgresql`

Comment: Причем тут bash вообще? CREATE TABLE Вы вводите, находясь в psql

Comment: `sudo -u postrgres psql` ввод команды в командную строку оболочки linux, `CREATE TABLE...` команда sql. Думаю вам следует уточнить вопрос, что бы он был понятен остальным

Comment: @alezhu Прояснил вопрос

Comment: @ipatev_nn прояснил вопрос

Comment: Смотрите, у `psql` есть встроенный набор ключей, в котором содержится например ключ `-c выполнить одну команду`, понять какие команды поддерживает psql можно выполнив в терминале `psql --help`. Отсюда получается что команда будет выглядеть следующим образом: `sudo -u postrgres psql -c "CREATE TABLE images...;"` если имя подключаемой базы используется по умолчанию

Comment: Команда `echo` выводит на печать данные в `stdout`, многие программы поддерживают обработку данного потока, к примеру `echo "123" | sed 's/3/5/g'` т.е. в данном случае программа sed примет на вхождение поток stdout через пайп и заменит тройку на пятерку. Думаю вам просто нужно прочитать про работу командной строки терминала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте файл с нужными командами, допустим вы назвали его `init-db.sql`. Также создайте файл `init-db.sh`, с ним удобнее запускать команду psql и особенно передавать ей параметры.

В `init-db.sh` напишите:

```
#!/bin/bash

# далее укажите пароль пользователя postgres
PGPASSWORD=парольбд
psql -f init-db.sql
```

Опция `-f` указывает что нужно выполнить команды из файла `init-db.sql`.

Чтоб это все запустить используйте команду:

```
sudo -u postgres init-db.sh
```